# opeing form in other form , C# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

im trying to make a main screen that i open all my others forms in it , and i want it will be elegant , so i did something like that

[image]

and the code is like that

```
   this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            City CityForm = new City();
            CityForm.MdiParent = this;
            CityForm.Show();
            CityForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

but the problem is when i open another form and another form .. all the forms stay and i think is not effective and smart

so someone have another way to do it ?

Comment: how about not writing your code in Hebrew?

Comment: The code is written in english , im using hebrew text because this is a school project..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you consider using a tabbed interface for this? Something like the editor part of Visual Studio where you have all open files (source code and forms) as single tabs? Personally I consider this far more elegant than an MDI interface.

To do this, create `UserControl`s instead of forms for your content. When a new "View" should be opened, add a tab to the `TabControl` and create an instance of the respective `UserControl`. Add this `UserControl` to the tab and set the `Dock` property to `Fill`.

This is very easy and the users today are more aquainted to tabbed interfaces than to MDI interfaces.

Comment: yea , im gonna use it now . Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You will have to keep a single copy of `City CityForm`, and reuse that each time you wish to create a new form (so as a member variable)

Have a look at [Form.IsMdiContainer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer.aspx)  and the use of `Form mdiChildForm` which should be close to how you should use `City CityForm`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think i'll use TabControl. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would work with TabControl, it's an elegant way to present several forms on the same place: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

> A TabControl contains tab pages, which are represented by TabPage
>   objects that you add through the TabPages property. The order of tab
>   pages in this collection reflects the order the tabs appear in the
>   control. The user can change the current TabPage by clicking one of
>   the tabs in the control.

Comment: Well i serach for that and im think that's easy to use and look great.

I will use it , Thanks !

Comment: Hm , i change it  and if i want to display a form in the tabcontrol i need to use this code ? 


Form f = new Form();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            f.BackColor = Color.Green;
            f.Visible = true;
            tabPage1.Controls.Add(f);

Comment: There is an example here, take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CityForm.ShowDialog()` instead of `CityForm.Show()`.

Comment: This makes the form application modal - this is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'dock' the form into the MDI Container;

```
City CityForm f1 = new City();
City.MdiParent = this;
City.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
City.Show();
```

Then you can just close the forms when you wish.

However, if you want it done automatically then i'd look into a tabbed interface as **Thorsten Dittmar** has suggested.